# Does Google TV need things like WakeLocks?

Tags: android, google-tv

I can't seem to find this info in the docs...

On a phone or tablet I understand we need things like acquiring WakeLocks and WifiLocks because of battery consumption. However, on a TV that's constantly plugged in I can't imagine a need for these.

So, on a Google TV:

- Does the screen stay on the entire time?
- Does the screen ever dim?
- Does the CPU stay on the entire time?
- Do I ever need to worry about things like [WakeLocks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html), [WifiLocks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html), or [MulticastLocks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is only with the Logitech Revue, which controls the TV over HDMI. As such, it has limited control over power save features. That said, here's my experiences with it...

> Does the screen stay on the entire time?

Yes. It's always sending a signal.

> Does the screen ever dim?

No, but it does have a screensaver that turns on after a while.
Presumably, you could use a wakelock to disable this (though I've never tested it).

> Does the CPU stay on the entire time?

I'd like to think that the CPU can throttle itself down if it's idle, the same as most desktops/laptops. I've never instrumented it to test though.

This shouldn't be something your app needs to worry about though.

> Do I ever need to worry about things like WakeLocks, WifiLocks, or MulticastLocks?

WakeLocks = Possibly, to disable the screensaver.

WifiLocks/MulticastLocks = Probably not, but it's good practice to do so anyway. It will make porting your application between devices easier, and it's always possible something will change in the future as GTV is deployed on more devices.